# Punctuation for lists

Tags: punctuation, word-order, colons

I have a sentence like this:

> As you can see, there are two projects "project1" and "project2", where the latter uses the global wrapper functions defined in "project1" project.

My question is how do I correctly write this sentence in terms of enumerating words "project1" and "project2". What I thought of was adding a colon like this:

> As you can see, there are two projects: "project1" and "project2", where the latter uses the global wrapper functions defined in "project1" project.

But somehow this doesn't feel fine. Can you please advise?

Comment: Why not just use a comma where you have a colon, and set off the names as a parenthetical insertion?

Comment: oh, excelent, you mean like this:
there are two projects ("project1" and "project2") where the...

Comment: Either that, or just use commas. There are two projects, project1 and project2, where the...

Comment: ok, great that can work for me - you can make it an answer so I can accept it. thx!

Comment: I'd also recommend either *defined in the "project1" project* or better still, just *defined in "project1"*. As is isn't wrong, but the repetition just reads a bit strangely.

Comment: @JonHanna: oh, yes that reads strangely, but in my original version those quoted words are not actually "project1" nor "project2" but instead they are the names of the actual projects, which I couldn't reference here in full because of some possible legal issues from which I would want to refrain myself.

Comment: In that case the repetition isn't an issue, though my suggestion may read still read better. On the other hand it might read much worse, depending on those names you can't reveal.

Comment: When someone downvotes - it's polite to say at least why.

Comment: @Nikola the irony being that this is an English Language & Usage site; surely someone who can't well-express why they are voting something down, isn't in a position to judge a question or answer's value. I prefer to comment and not vote, since the author might address the comment in an edit, or have a good argument to counter mine.

Comment: @JonHanna: and I think that's perfectly fine. I'm only wondering why those who downvoted didn't say it in the comments like "hey, your question is lousy" or something like that :). Ah, nevermind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Using "project1" and "project2" can be clumsy, so I'm going to call them Alpha and Beta instead. There are some minor changes to word-order because of that.]

The list of projects isn't essential to the sentence (if the reference to "the latter" is removed as well):

> As you can see, there are two projects, where Beta uses the global wrapper functions defined in project Alpha.

To insert something into that sentence, put it in *parenthesis* — either using brackets or commas or dashes:

> As you can see, there are two projects, Alpha and Beta, where the latter uses the global wrapper functions defined in project Alpha.
>
> As you can see, there are two projects (Alpha and Beta) where the latter uses the global wrapper functions defined in project Alpha.
>
> As you can see, there are two projects — Alpha and Beta — where the latter uses the global wrapper functions defined in project Alpha.

With this, a pedant would say that you cannot use "the latter" to refer to Beta. Parenthetical content should be able to be removed without changing the sense of the sentence.

It's actually easier to read if you repeat the word Beta, because the reader doesn't have to go back to find out what "the latter" is. And it satisfies the pedants. I like dashes, but commas would work.

> As you can see, there are two projects — Alpha and Beta — where Beta uses the global wrapper functions defined in project Alpha.

Comment: As a sidenote, *parenthesis* in "American" English are the rounded brackets, (), but the parenthetical business of the commas would be the same. As for the dashes, it might be a little non-standard for the US, but punctuation is often a stylistic and individualized concern.

Comment: @Adam Are you sure rounded brackets are not called *parentheses* (plural)? [*Parenthesis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29) is the rhetorical device.

Comment: Yes, *parenthesis* also appears to be the singular of *parentheses*--I missed that nuance when looking it up but won't make that spelling mistake again.

Comment: I would ordinarily call the *parenthesis* an *appositive phrase* rather than a *parenthesis*, to avoid confusion with the punctuation name--That isn't really an issue though if you call the *parentheses* brackets.

Comment: It might also have been a bit clearer if I had put the *in* in italics too: "put it *in parenthesis*."